# Rails 4: InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am on the site of my app: `subdomain.lvh.me:3000/new` with

```
= link_to "Delete", item_url(@item, subdomain: ""), method: :delete
```

If I click on that link, I get redirected to the right url but I get this error:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in ItemsController#destroy
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

**Sidenotes:**

- I am using devise to handle users.
- A Local storage object gets
  created for `http://lvh.me:3000/`

*Any idea why this is happening? Devise itself works across all subdomains.*

**Log:**

```
Started DELETE "/items/322146979" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-13 18:03:18 +0100
Processing by ItemsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"subdomain"=>"", "id"=>"322146979"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but is `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` present in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not because of the Devise, youre passing subdomain as empty, so it redirects_to http://lvh.me:3000/ and you're on http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000. So it's considering as a separate site. So it raised a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) authenticity token.

Comment: I configured devise to work on subdomain and main domain

Comment: I need to pass subdomain as empty to go to the right url

Comment: Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', domain: :all have you added this line in the configuration?

Comment: I have.  .      .        .  .